# No hibernate session when bootstrapping data with multiple databases in grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

i have trouble to save domain class objects into dbs other then the default dataSource. it should be said that I can read from the log database, but can not save (UserLog.list() works). when i run the app, saving the UserLog object triggers the error below.

dataSource.groovy:

```
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "create-drop"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db1"
        username = "postgres"
        password = "postgres"
        driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    }
    dataSource_log {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db2"
        username = "postgres"
        password = "postgres"
        driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    }
}
```

log.UserLog:

```
class UserLog{
    ...
    static mapping = {
        id generator: "hilo"
        version false
        datasource 'log'
    }
}
```

conf/bootstrap.groovy:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import happyfloat.Address

import java.text.DateFormat
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

import log.UserLog

class BootStrap {

    def list = []
    def dataSource_log
    Random rand = new Random()

    def init = { servletContext ->

        Address a1 = new Address() // domain in dataSource [does work!]**
        a1.save()

        UserLog ul = new UserLog() // domain in dataSource_log [ fails! ]**
        ul.save()

    }

    def destroy = {

    }
}
```

error:

```
    | Error 2013-05-20 20:11:48,739 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    Message: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    Line | Method
    | Error 2013-05-20 20:11:48,964 [Thread-9] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin  - Error configuration scaffolding: Error creating bean with name 'instanceControllersApi': Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    Message: Error creating bean with name 'instanceControllersApi': Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    Line | Method
    ->> 722 | run in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: Have you tried using `withTransaction` surrounding `UserLog` save?

Answer (score 6):

Example of what @dmahapatro suggested:

```
UserLog.withTransaction {
    UserLog ul = new UserLog()
    ul.save()
}
```

This will create a transaction for that datasource (if you didn't understand already)